# Dealing with Dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Here's what I need to do:

1. I want to insert a date into a datetime MySQL field 30 days from from the current date
2. When I pull that specific record, I want to be able to check whether that date has passed yet or not (i.e. expiration date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your insert:

```
$thirty_days_from_today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60*60*24*30);
```

Checking expiration dates:

```
if(strtotime($row['expiration_date']) < time()) {
    // expired
}
```

Comment: This looks like everything I need :D I might combine it with some of the other tips, particularly using MySQL to insert it as an interval. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO the_table
   (fields, the_date_field)
VALUES
   (?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

---

```
SELECT
   the_date_field < NOW() AS expired
FROM
   the_table
```

Confirm:

```
SELECT '2010-01-01' < NOW() AS expired;
+---------+
| expired |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

SELECT '2012-01-01' < NOW() AS expired;
+---------+
| expired |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
```

Comment: How does the_date_field < NOW() AS expired  work? Does "expired" become a variable?

Comment: When you fetch data, 'expired' will be the key.  For example, using `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc()`, `$row` would be `array('expired' => true);`

Comment: Ahhh, I see. And it would return false if the date is > NOW()? Sounds perfect :D

Comment: Indeed it will.  You can confirm this yourself using the mysql prompt:

Note that as in php, 0 == false and 1 == true.

Code looks pretty awful; adding to my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation. This looks like the best way to do what I need to do in the fewest lines of code, which is always great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a big fan of minimizing lines of code down to characters.  It's a sickness, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Strtotime is your friend on this one, both for ensuring that the input you're sending through data is "understandable" by PHP and also for doing math such as "+10 days" which would return the date ten days from today.  It's really amazing what you can throw at strtotime.

Checking dates is as simple in a MySQL query or PHP comparison with an operator -- Like >, < <>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP, you can utilize `strtotime()`

```
$date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '+30 days' ) );
```

`strtotime` can handle other increments (`+1 days`, `+5 minutes`, etc)

You can also use `strtotime` to compare the dates when you read them out of the database.  If you're storing in full-day (no timestamp) format, you'll need to divide by a full day's worth of seconds.

```
$expdate = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', $record[ 'expiration_date' ] ) );
$today = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
$isExpired = round( abs( $expiration - $today ) / ( 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) >= 0;
```